# Cast a Rust enum to a sub-enum

Tags: enums, rust, casting, code-generation, reusability

I'm creating subsets of [std::sync::atomic::Ordering](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html):

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;

pub enum StoreOrdering {
    Relaxed,
    Release,
    SeqCst
}
impl Into<Ordering> for StoreOrdering {
    fn into(self) -> Ordering {
        match self {
            Self::Relaxed => Ordering::Relaxed,
            Self::Release => Ordering::Release,
            Self::SeqCst  => Ordering::SeqCst
        }
    }
}
impl std::convert::TryFrom<Ordering> for StoreOrdering {
    type Error = (); // HACK
    fn try_from(ord: Ordering) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match ord {
            Ordering::Relaxed => Ok(Self::Relaxed),
            Ordering::Release => Ok(Self::Release),
            Ordering::SeqCst  => Ok(Self::SeqCst),
            _ => Err(())
        }
    }
}

enum LoadOrdering {
    Acquire,
    Relaxed,
    SeqCst
}
// ???
```

As you can see, now I need to write those two `impl`s with `match`es again for `StoreOrdering <-> LoadOrdering` and maybe even for `StoreOrdering <-> LoadOrdering` - as well as for any enum subset. How to avoid such boilerplate?

Comment: I don't know of any way not to make these implementations. They need to be there somewhere. The best option (depending on how many conversions you need) is probably a macro that you can create yourself. However, if this is it, then I'd just leave it. It's not that much really.

Comment: @Geoxion that's sad. I want to change C++ for Rust at least for some time but I can't because of its templates which e.g. solve this problem. I wish Rust supported this feature just like OOP languages do with their subtype casting.

Comment: Rust doesn't do ducktyping (except sorta kinda in macros like you'd expect). There's probably a better solution, so what is it that you're trying to solve with these enums?

Comment: In case you're interested in the macro, though, I've made one here in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c646363dae534eb07101fbffe9e7e2b4

Comment: @Geoxion I'm writing `AtomicRef` based on std `AtomicPtr`. `AtomicPtr::load()` and `AtomicPtr::store()` receive `Ordering` and panic if it's not from the expected subset of `Ordering` - I found it silly and wanted quality compile-time checking (for my `AtomicRef`) instead, so... this question was born. Your macro seems interesting, I should try it.

Comment: @Geoxion that's a cool macro! I believe it should be `#[sub_enum(Ordering)]` (procedural?) for composability.

Comment: Procedural macros are pretty overkill for this - you can write declarative macros in a way that passes through attributes/documentation if that's what you want, and that avoids having to compile and run another crate at compile time.

Comment: @Geoxion I suggest posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust doesn't support duck typing like C++ does with templates. The only functionality that generics can access is determined by the trait bounds.

So any duck-type-like behaviour must be done with macros.

For this, you could use the given macro below.
It only works for simple C-style macros. It creates the enum and auto-generates the conversions to the given super-enum.

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;
use std::convert::TryInto;

// Create the store ordering
sub_enum!(StoreOrdering of Ordering {
    Relaxed,
    Release,
    SeqCst
});

// Create the load ordering
sub_enum!(LoadOrdering of Ordering {
    Acquire,
    Relaxed,
    SeqCst
});

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! sub_enum {
    ($sub_enum_name:ident of $super_enum_name:ty {
        $($variant:ident),* $(,)?
    }) => {
        pub enum $sub_enum_name {
            $($variant,)*
        }
        
        impl From<$sub_enum_name> for $super_enum_name {
            fn from(val: $sub_enum_name) -> $super_enum_name {
                match val {
                    $(<$sub_enum_name>::$variant => <$super_enum_name>::$variant,)*
                }
            }
        }
        
        impl std::convert::TryFrom<$super_enum_name> for $sub_enum_name {
            type Error = ();
            fn try_from(val: $super_enum_name) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
                match val {
                    $(<$super_enum_name>::$variant => Ok(Self::$variant),)*
                    _ => Err(())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let store = StoreOrdering::SeqCst;
    let general: Ordering = store.into();
    let load: LoadOrdering = general.try_into().unwrap();
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c646363dae534eb07101fbffe9e7e2b4)

A lot could be improved still, of course.
However, this should do for your problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

There's a crate called [subenum](https://crates.io/crates/subenum) that has a derive macro for automating the creation of the `SubEnum` and the conversions `From<SubEnum> for SuperEnum` and `TryFrom<SuperEnum> for SubEnum`.

Here's an example from the crate's readme:

```rust
use subenum::subenum;

#[subenum(Edible)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Plant {
    #[subenum(Edible)]
    Basil,
    #[subenum(Edible)]
    Tomato,
    Manzanita,
    Pine,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), EdibleConvertError> {
    let plant = Plant::Tomato;

    // We can convert between them.
    let edible = Edible::try_from(plant)?;
    let _plant2 = Plant::from(edible);

    // We can compare them.
    assert_eq!(plant, edible);

    // We derive anything that's derived on the parent, such as clone.
    let edible2 = edible.clone();

    Ok(())
}
```